# Why would the Gestapo help Jews to escape?

Tags: world-war-two, nazi-germany, jews, nazism, denmark

This [history.com](https://www.history.com/news/wwii-danish-jews-survival-holocaust) article says

> Passage was a terrifying ordeal. Jews congregated in fishing towns, then hid on small boats, usually 10 to 15 at a time. They gave their children sleeping pills and sedatives to keep them from crying, and struggled to maintain control during the hour-long crossing. **Some boats, like the Gerda III, were boarded by Gestapo patrols.** Others sailed with gas obtained by careful rationing in towns like Elsinore, where the “Elsinore Sewing Club,” a resistance unit, helped a few hundred Jews make the crossing.

I am not a native English speaker. But for this sentence below, I think it's saying that the Gestapo is helping boarding the boat?

> Some boats, like the Gerda III, were boarded by Gestapo patrols.

Why Gestapo would help the Jews to escape?

Comment: *the Gestapo is helping boarding the boat* - No. The Gestapo are the ones boarding or getting onto the boat (to search it for illegal cargo, etc.)

Comment: "Boarding" means "entering the vehicle". The context is that the refugee jews sedated the children so the Gestapo patrols would not notice them when they got on board.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I think this is more of an ELL question but from what I understand from the context as well as [this article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rescue_of_the_Danish_Jews), the boarding of the patrols is to apprehend the Jews, not to help them.

As per the article, emphasis mine:

> During the first days of the rescue action, Jews moved into the many fishing harbors on the Danish coast to await passage, but **officers of the Gestapo became suspicious of activity around harbors** (and on the night of October 6, about 80 Jews were caught hiding in the loft of the church at Gilleleje, their hiding place having been betrayed by a Danish girl who was in love with a German soldier).Subsequent rescues had to take place from isolated points along the coast. While waiting their turn, the **Jews took refuge in the woods and in cottages away from the coast, out of sight of the Gestapo**.

> Some of the refugees never made it to Sweden; a few chose to commit suicide; some were **captured by the Gestapo** en route to their point of embarkation; some 23 were lost at sea when vessels of poor seaworthiness capsized; and still others were intercepted at sea by German patrol boats. Danish harbor police and civil police often cooperated with the rescue effort. During the early stages, the Gestapo was undermanned and the German army and navy were called in to reinforce the Gestapo in its effort to prevent transportation taking place; but by and large the German military troops proved less than enthusiastic in the operation and frequently turned a blind eye to escapees. The local Germans in command, for their own political calculations and through their own inactivity, may have actually facilitated the escape.